# MySql 8.0.15 install failure Invalid Server Template

Tags: mysql

This is my first MySql install from the ground up.
I am using Windows Server 2016, trying to install MySql 8.0.15.  I am doing this to try and use it  with php 7.3.1.

The install has all the listed prerequisites.

When I get the config section of mysql insstaller, it breaks on the first response with an error of "Beginning configuration step: Writing configuration file

```
Invalid server template

Ended configuration step: Writing configuration file"

The system event log has one error, "The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID 
{8D8F4F83-3594-4F07-8369-FC3C3CAE4919}
 and APPID 
{F72671A9-012C-4725-9D2F-2A4D32D65169}
 to the user NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM SID (S-1-5-18) from address LocalHost (Using LRPC) running in the application container Unavailable SID (Unavailable). This security permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative tool."
```

But I'm not sure this is even the right troubleshooting path to start down.

Can you assist with some guidance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up uninstalling all mysql 8 components that had already installed. 
Then went back and got the mysql installer 5.7.25.0. I think I had some trouble after that, but it wasn't the same error. I finally ended up installing mysql 8.0.15 by itself and it worked. Then I went back and did the connectors. Next the workbench. Finally docs and samples. Doing them one at a time seemed to go better. I am now up and running.

Comment: After 2 hours of painfull installing & uninstalling I stranded here. I thought I was doing something wrong, looks like the 8.0.15 installer is not working. Will try this approach

Comment: Looks like the installer is working fine- 
All you have to do is accept updates in the first dialog & be sure that you have nothing mysql related installed. Otherwise it will crash. IDK why im just happy that it finally works

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem with the 
`mysql-installer-web-community`.

The `mysql-installer-community` was working without a problem.

The bottom link is the none web installer which was working.

[image]

Comment: I got this approach to work but only after completely uninstalling the 'web' version first and then installing the full version.

Answer (score 2):

For me initially when I was not accepting the initial update mysql pop-up then installer was not working, but once I accepted it. Then it successfully worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to install after getting the same error.
I have changed the credentials for the sql root. 
By default, host is set to something like %ALL_HOST%. I changed to localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did to fix the issue

- completely removed mySQL Server and Workbench installations.
- uninstalled the mySQL web installer. Restarted my computer.
- ran the mySQL web installer again (only installing mySQL Server)
- downloaded the mySQL Workbench installer to install Workbench separately