# How to resolve writing configuration error while installing mysql?

Tags: mysql, windows

I am new to MySQL. I downloaded the MySQL windows installer and selected I guess everything I thought I would need for x64 and x86 products especially utilities, workbench and MySQL Server for MYSQL 8.0.15

When I get to the Configuration Steps section I select Execute and this is what happens:

> Writing Configuration file turns red.

Next I checked the Log File:

The Log File states:

> Beginning configuration step: Writing Configuration File
>
> Invalid server template
>
> Ended configuration step: Writing configuration file.

Comment: I had the same issue, when I checked the installer logs found at "C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Installer for Windows\Logs" it stated "mysql-installer Error: 50 : Input string was not in a correct format."
Leading me to try a different combination of older installer versions and older MySQL server versions. I also updated Visual C++ for both 32 and 64 and all of a sudden the installer worked. Sorry I can't help you with a more specific solution.

Comment: Possible similar question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29866381/mysql-server-5-7-installation-fails-at-writing-configuration-file

Comment: Also check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55079211/mysql-8-0-15-install-failure-invalid-server-template

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySql 8.0.15 install failure Invalid Server Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55079211/mysql-8-0-15-install-failure-invalid-server-template)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide us with your windows version. Supposing it's windows 10, which by default, has restricted use of certain part of the system drive (C:) to mitigate security breach .  Try disabling the mechanics by the following steps:

1. Press win + r to open up the Run window. Enter regedit to start the registry window.
2. Go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\
3. Set the value of EnableLUA in the right part of the window to 0.
4. Bounce the box.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31418703)